# Problema ressetar $_POST

Tags: php, ajax

Pessoal to com um problema nesse trecho de código, ele avalia se existe a variável `$_POST['employee_id']` caso existir ela ira dar um update, se não existir ele da um insert! até ai tudo bem tudo funcionando, porem se eu der um update e depois for dar um insert ele executa o update no lugar do insert, acho porque a variável `$_POST['employee_id']` deve ter ficado na memoria, lembrando que isso tudo ocorre via ajax sem refresh na pagina, já pesquisei sobre isso e não consegui resolver ja tenter dar `unset` na `$_POST` setala como um array null, como vcs podem vem... porem nada funcionou, Agradeço desde já!

```
// Se update
if(isset($_POST['employee_id']) AND $_POST['employee_id'] != '') {
    $id = $_POST['employee_id'];
    $user = Container::getModel("Client");
    $this->view->clients = $user->update($data, $id);

    if(isset($this->view->clients)){
        unset($_POST['employee_id']);
        $_POST = array();
        echo json_encode(["update"=>true,"msg"=>"Cadastro atualizado com <strong>sucesso!</strong>"]);exit;
    }else{
        echo json_encode(["status"=>false,"msg"=>"Desculpe ocorreu um<strong> Erro!</strong>"]);exit;
    }
// Se não insert
}else{
    $user = Container::getModel("Client");
    $this->view->clients = $user->insert($data);
    if(isset($this->view->clients)){
        $this->view->last_client = $user->find($this->view->clients);
        echo json_encode(["insert"=>true,"msg"=>"Cadastro realizado com <strong>sucesso!</strong>","clients"=>$this->view->last_client]);exit;
    }else{
        echo json_encode(["status"=>false,"msg"=>"Desculpe ocorreu um<strong> Erro!</strong>"]);exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é porque falta o `unset` no `insert` também?

Comment: no caso ele avalia isto antes de cair no insert, só se a `$_POST['employee_id']` não existir que ele cai no insert,  se eu recarregar a page e der um inserte ele insere normalmente, o problema é depois do primeiro update, ai o insert vira update.. kkk

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com um simples `$('#employee_id').val('');`, Agradeço!